# android startActivityForResult giving error

Tags: android

I am new to android can someone help me please, following is the code i tried to run for scanning the barcode but it gives an error whenever i click the button it says force to close what should i do help me please.

```
this.btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);
this.btnCheck.setOnClickListener(
new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v)
{
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
}
);   
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 0) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
Toast.makeText(this, "the scaned code is = "+ contents, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
// Handle successful scan
} else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
// Handle cancel
}
}
}
```

Edit Logcat:

this is the log cat now Starting:

```
Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) } from pid 359 thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560) 

08-18 01:52:00.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(359): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 

08-18 01:52:00.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(359): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) } 

08-18 01:52:00.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(359): at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
```

Comment: @izhar - First, check that your manifest has defined the target activity correctly. If so, then for us to help, you need to show us the stack trace when it crashed. Open the logcat view in Eclipse (Window > Show View > LogCat). Run the app and when it crashes, you should be able to see the stack trace in the logcat window. (It might help to maximize the LogCat window for this.) Copy the stack trace and add it to your question.

Comment: just curious, can you give a non zero requestCode and tell us what happens. Or tell us where exactly it crashes.

Comment: this is the log cat now

Starting: Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) } from pid 359
 thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-18 01:52:00.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(359): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 01:52:00.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(359): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) }
08-18 01:52:00.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(359):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)

Comment: @Sam.. non zero requestCode gives the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception probably means that the device you are trying to use doesn't have BarcodeScanner installed. You can use this code somewhere in your app to check, and prompt the user to install it form the market if they do not already have.

```
      //Check for Barcode scanner, if not found put up an alert that allows user to install it.
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.google.zxing.client.android", 0);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
         new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("WARNING:")
            .setMessage("You don't have Barcode Scanner installed. Please install it.")
             .setCancelable(false)
            .setNeutralButton("Install it now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {         
                          Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.google.zxing.client.android");
                          startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
                    }
            })
            .show();
    }
```

Edit: Change this line:

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
```

to this:

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
```

I highly suggest you [go to this page](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) Read it thoroughly, and then follow the two links that are underneath the code example and look at all of the code that it shows. Even if you do not understand it, it will give you some idea what is capable via Intents with the BarcodeScanner app.

Comment: @Tim.. after pressing the "Install it now" button it still gives the error as stated above

Comment: 08-18 12:25:44.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(485): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://search?q=pname:com.google.zxing.client.android }
08-18 12:25:44.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(485):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
08-18 12:25:44.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(485):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
08-18 12:25:44.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(485):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)

Comment: What device are you using? Try going to the market and downloading BarcodeScanner before you run yourapplication.

Comment: thanks for your help buddies it works now.. but i want to scan the book ISBN but it only scans the dots like code can someone tell me please what is the scan mode for scanning the book isbn??

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.google.zxing.client.android")));
        }
```

Comment: Code answers are best with some explanation. Please add some context to your answer.